# Nature on the islands near Thailand

Tags: field-recording, nature-recording, reference

Hello all,

Looking for some references regarding types of nature found on the islands near Thailand, some of which are resort locales and others, I assume, are mostly uninhabited. I realize that there are many, many islands in this part of the world and don't need exact species (although that would be nice!), just some general guidelines. Mostly would like to know what types of sounds can be heard near the beach, both day and night. Dense birds and insects? Sparse? Any sea birds to speak of?

Appreciate only specific responses, rather than suggestions on how to make it sound "jungle-y". Thanks!

Comment: Hey Jay, I know this is an older post but I recently purchased this library called - AUTHENTIC THAILAND VOL. 1-3 and it's great. It does include a good amount of Island around Thailand

Comment: Hi Luke! Thanks for your reply to this ancient SSD post. Appreciate your recommendation!

Answer (score 3):

Here are some examples. You can listen for yourself :-)

I recorded these over 6 years ago, these are actually some of my first recordings. In other words, they don't sound good...

Here's the link to all three: http://soundcloud.com/soundplusdesign/sets/islandreferences I named them with all the info I have.

Just to contextualize, here's some info on the island: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haad_Khuad

And this is what it looked like:

[image]
<sub>(source: [bottlebeach.com](http://www.bottlebeach.com/images2/Bottlebeach2.gif))</sub>

Comment: @Andrew, thank you -- excellent answer and just what I needed.

Comment: Sure thing @Jay, glad I could help a little. 

Answer (score 2):

As you rightly suggested, the sounds vary depending on the size of the island and how developed it is. An island like Phuket is very big (550 sq. KM) with over 300 000 residents, plus probably twice as many tourists at any one time. Therefore, human-generated noise becomes part of the overall ambiance and also disturbs the natural sonic environment which exists.

One sound that I noticed was very prominent everywhere in Thailand was the cicadas. However, these vary greatly depending on the natural environment they are in. For example, I was on a small, relatively unknown island called Koh Phayam on Thailand's West coast and there was a jungle in the middle of the island. Here, the cicadas were singing in chorus very intensely (there must have been literally thousands of them on each tree). On more built up islands (the touristy Ko Phi Phi Don for example) the cicadas are much less intense. Another factor that makes a difference is the time of day. I noticed that the cicada calls varied depending on the time of day.

In terms of bird calls, I'm no birdwatcher so I can't give you names of species, but I've uploaded a little mix of the various ambiances I captured around the country which features some bird calls as well as the cicada variations I've already discussed. Again with the bird calls, a lot depends on the type and size of the island. I hope it helps.

[soundcloud]colin-hunter/thailand-nature[/soundcloud]

Comment: Yip, cicadas drown everything!

Comment: @Colin, thanks for the sample and the information - very, very helpful!

Comment: @ Jay - Glad to help!

Comment: Cicadas!  That's what I remember the most.  Did you know there are thousands of species of cicadas that each take turns singing throughout the day?  If you know what to listen for it's possible to tell the time of day within 5 minutes just by the sound of the cicadas.  So if you really wanted to be accurate......

Comment: @Brenden - Awesome piece of trivia!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it helps to check out some home movies of vacations at the spot you're trying to figure out the sound for.

This is what I found from a quick search:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tXggzZA1m8&feature=fvwrel

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwEJi6wSQpA&feature=fvwrel

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oN1jDqPJrtA

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jx5acTubIPE&feature=related

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DsQ8DkAVMZg&NR=1

Got to love the wind on the camera mics.

Comment: @Jay No prob. Hope that gives you some idea.. I can also ask the Thai voice talents I work with if they remember what types of birds they hear when they go back to Thailand.